# accessing variables from custom ArrayAdapter in yes/no dialog

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

Hi i want my code to have separated methods to create yes/no dialog and to create its *onClickListener* separated from **ArrayAdapter** (I'm not sure if *dialogCreator()* is done well but that's not the case in that question)

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

```
public class FlashCardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileManager> {
interface Callback {
    void onFileDeleted(String fileName);
}

private final Callback mCallback;

public FlashCardsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileManager> users, final Callback callback) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    mCallback = callback;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final FileManager manager = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView mainTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deck_name_id);

    Button addCardButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_add_card);

    Button deleteDeckButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete);

    mainTextView.setText(manager.getFileName());

    mainTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FlashCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    addCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                manager.deleteFile(); // I want to access manager in here
                mCallback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName()); // and here
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void dialogCreator(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    builder.create();
}

}
```

*manager* is the variable I'd like to access in my methods

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a `variable` outside a `method` in the same `class`, you have to set the focus of the `variable` to *class* (at the moment your variable is method-private).

You can achieve it simply moving your `manager` variable outside the `getView` method:

```
public class FlashCardsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileManager> {
interface Callback {
    void onFileDeleted(String fileName);
}

private final Callback mCallback;
private FileManager manager; //in this way this variable is accessible to all method inside the class

public FlashCardsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileManager> users, final Callback callback) {
    super(context, 0, users);
    mCallback = callback;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    manager = getItem(position); //here you initialize it

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView mainTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deck_name_id);

    Button addCardButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_add_card);

    Button deleteDeckButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete);

    mainTextView.setText(manager.getFileName());

    mainTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FlashCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    addCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                manager.deleteFile(); // and here you can access it
                mCallback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName()); // and here too
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void dialogCreator(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    builder.create();
}

}
```

Hope this helps, if I miss-understood tell me

## Note:

Probably would be a better approach to save a reference of the list in your adapter and retrieve items (FileManager) from the position (overriding `getItem(position)` methos too) to avoid recycler related problems.

Comment: First of sorry for answering so late, yes for sure I could make it as private class variable but I was wondering about some other (may be better) way to do that. I just thought that there may be some 'ready' pattern to do that but now i think that there's no, and that this solution with private class varriable is okeish.